# Which NSColor should I use for text in an NSPopover?

Tags: cocoa, nspopover, nscolor, human-interface

What are the correct NSColors for text in NSPopovers (as displayed in iTunes 12)? I did not find this information in the HIG and I'm not sure how to find out otherwise (matching up color values in Digital Color Meter to a list somewhere?) Here is a screenshot:

http://imgur.com/dSFYcla

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use system colors, such as `+[NSColor controlTextColor]`.

Or use the new `labelColor`, `secondaryLabelColor`, etc, which will blend vibrantly in the popover. iTunes is likely using labelColor for the main text, and secondaryLabelColor for the subtext.